# Div not auto-sizing in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, cross-browser

Anyone care to check this page out in any web dev tool (Firebug, IE9, Chrome Dev Tools) and tell me why the #container div would not be auto-sizing in Firefox?  There is supposed to be a background shadow, which is visible in most browsers, but not showing up in FF.  Thoughts?

http://d2burke.com/hosted/vaacme/

Thanks!

Comment: I see that in Firefox, the css is slightly different: "url("../images/PageShadow.png") repeat-y scroll 0 0 transparent" compared to "background: url(http://d2burke.com/hosted/vaacme/images/PageShadow.png) repeat-y;" in Chrome. Do you know what causes this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since *all* elements inside `#container` are floated, everything inside it is taken out of the normal document flow, and thus it shrinks to nothingness, since it has zero padding and height. To fix this you can either apply:

```
#container {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

or remove:

```
.break {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: overflow:hidden did the trick. So why does floating all elements "take [everyting] out of the normal document flow"?

Comment: @d2burke That's how floating works - it takes that particular element out of the normal top to down flow and shifts it left or right depending on the value you defined for the `float` property. See this for more info: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/floatclear